# Extract multiple link and click in console using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am pretty new to this Jquery extraction. My problem right now is to make the links I extracted automatically clicked through code in Chrome console. I used the code below to get the link in the href, but the `click(),trigger('click')` function doesn't work in this situation. Can someone give some suggestions? Thanks in advance

```
$('.agent-info').find('a').href.trigger('click')
```

Comment: did you try `$('.agent-info').find('a').trigger('click')`

Comment: Remove href from code and try.

Comment: I tried, but it only returns the value of <'a'> rather than clicking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `request` and `cheerio` modules in NodeJs to load page contents and get all bodies.

```
let request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    q = require('q')
```

You need a function which get `url` and load the page

```
function loadPage(url) {
    var deferred = q.defer();

    request.get({
        url: url,
        timeout: 60000
    },
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error) {
                deferred.resolve(body);
            }
            else {
                deferred.reject(error);
            }
        }
    );

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

You need to find all links in the body. For that use a function like this

```
function extractLinks(body) {
    var deferred = q.defer(),
        $ = cheerio.load(body),
        links = [];

    $(/*Your selector*/).each(function() {
        // add links to links array
    });

    deferred.resolve(links);
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Then you must again load body of each item in `links` array. So use the `loadPage` module again. And a function using `cheerio` to extract your data of new pages.

```
loadPage(firstUrl)
    .then(function(result){
        extractLinks(result)
            .then(function(res){
                 var arr = [];
                 for(var r in res) {
                     arr.push(loadPage(res[r]));
                     q.all(arr)
                         .then()
                         .catch();
                 }
            });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I did not use Node.js because I am not very familiar with this part but thanks for providing the solution method. I used this solution logic and python scrapy  successfully got the data :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(".agent-info a").trigger("click");` instead. This is a simple example:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".agent-info a", function(){
    $(this).text("It works!");
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".agent-info a").trigger("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="agent-info">
    <a href="#">Click me 1</a>
    <a href="#">Click me 2</a>
    <a href="#">Click me 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: it replaces texts as "it works" but can not automatically click the link. I can use "$(".agent-info a").trigger("click").href" finds all the links, is there any way to conduct click on them?

Comment: Can you give me an example of those links? Try something like `window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');` in `click` event. @IrisZhanfu

Comment: there are multiple links like this. [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18EWAU_XJpzFZHQksVkouGYv9iZ2PQnE8). Because the data I want to extract is on the linked page, so I hope I can find a way, for each link on this page, click it first and then extract the data on the linked page. The page that included these clicked links is [link](https://corenyc.com/agents/)

Comment: I recommend you use NodeJs `request` module to request these links and get body, then use `cheerio` to extract data. Of course Not in Browser! I have some prepared codes for that. I put them in another answer.@IrisZhanfu