# Extract the info from a url in Node js and work with it

Tags: json, node.js, href

I everyone I am working with node js consuming the data from another api.

The answer is as you can see:

```
 "items": [
    {

"$ref": "http://sports.core.api.qa.espninfra.starwave.com/v2/sports/basketball/leagues/mens-college-basketball?lang=en"
    },
    {

"$ref": "http://sports.core.api.qa.espninfra.starwave.com/v2/sports/basketball/leagues/nba?lang=en"
    }
]
```

I need to expand the $ref url and extract the info of the call from this url, something like:

```
{

$ref": "http://sports.core.api.qa.espninfra.starwave.com/v2/sports/basketball/leagues/mens-college-basketball?lang=en",

 "id": "41",

"uid": "s:40~l:41",

"name": "NCAA Men's Basketball",
  etc....

}
```

I am not sure how to access the $ref key in node js and also if there is some library which allow me to expand and extract the info from this link.

This is my current code:

```
   function main() {
    var initializePromise = initialize('http://www.someurl.com');
    initializePromise.then(function(result) {
        userDetails = result;
        console.log("Initialized user details");
        return userDetails.items
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }).then(function(result) {

      //  console.log(result);
        result.forEach(function(value){
            console.log(value);
      //here I need to work with the links in value and extract and print the info
        });
    })
}
```

I am not sure if it is the correct implementation with promises,for what I can do, or could be a better option?

Comment: I recently answered a question like this, read my answer there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50148311/extract-multiple-link-and-click-in-console-using-jquery/50157030#50157030

Comment: Pick a module that can parse URLs. How about https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html